# how to split a line into array in shell

Tags: shell

below script is used for drop a mail while ping dropped in network

```
subject="Ping failed"
Email="test1@server.abc.com"
awk '{print $1}' < b.txt | while read ip;do
    CNT=$(ping -c 1 $ip  | grep 'received' | awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' | awk '{ print $1 }')
    if [ $CNT -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Host : $ip is down (ping failed) at $(date)"|  mail -s "$subject" $Email
    fi
done
```

This script is working fine. Input file has the following content..

```
192.2.165.1 ttcn
192.3.4.23 dct
192.3.4.24 abc
```

I want to split lines of this file into 0 and 1 index form like array and mail format should be

```
Host : $ip ttcn is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
```

can anyone help me to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read a line into an array use `read -a arr` and then access the elements using `${arr[0]}`, `${arr[1]}` etc.

Also, you don't need to parse the output of `ping` to check if the host responded. Just use the exit status instead.

Here is the revised version:

```
while read -r -a arr
do
    ip="${arr[0]}"
    if ! ping -q -c 1 "$ip" > /dev/null
    then
        mail -s "$subject" "$email" <<< "Host $ip is down (ping failed) at $(date)"
    fi
done < b.txt
```

Comment: `Great! its solved me what i was looking. another query here is there any way to create excelfile for capturing the output for the same. can we do this in shell?`

Answer (score 1):

Give multiple arguments to `read`, and each column will be read into the corresponding variable:

```
while read ip name;do
    CNT=$(ping -c 1 $ip  | awk -F',' '/received/ { split($2, a, " "); print a[1]}')
    if [ $CNT -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Host : $ip $name is down (ping failed) at $(date)"|  mail -s "$subject" $Email
    fi
done < b.txt
```

Comment: `thanks it works for me.` if I add 3 argument then what would be the split function? like 192.2.165.1 ttcn abc and mail format accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk`

```
 echo "192.2.165.1 ttcn" | awk ' { split($0,a,"");ip=a[1]; print $ip}'
```